# Recursive array parent match from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I want to create a function that gets the "parent" in a recursive array loop, and make an output array of those "used" parents.

It's a bit hard to explain, but take a look at the example:

```
const regions = [{
  name: 'Europe',
  subRegions: [{
    name: 'BeNeLux',
    territories: [{
      code: 'NL',
      name: 'Netherlands'
    }, {
      code: 'DE',
      name: 'Germany'
    }, {
      code: 'LU',
      name: 'Luxembourg'
    }]
  }],
  territories: [{
    code: 'UK',
    name: 'United Kingdom'
  }, {
    code: 'AL',
    name: 'Albania'
  }, {
    code: 'ZW',
    name: 'Switzerland'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Africa',
  territories: [{
    code: 'GH',
    name: 'Ghana'
  }]
}]

const selectedTerritories = ['NL', 'UK', 'GH']
```

At this point I need a function, that searches for all the TOP regions of a territory by code, so the output would look like this:

```
const activeRegions = ['Europe', 'Africa']
```

A thing to note is that, there is a subRegion within `Europe` (`BeNeLux`), and the recursion gets to that point, it should NOT return `BeNeLux` as an active region but `Europe` instead.

This is what I have tried, but has duplicate subregion names and it ignores the "parent" recursion discover requirement:

```
const getRegionsLabelFromTerritoryList = (activeTerritories, regions, activeRegions = []) => {
  regions.forEach((region) => {
    if (region.territories) {
      region.territories.forEach(t => {
        if (activeTerritories.includes(t.code)) {
          activeRegions.push(region)
        }
      })
    }

    if (region.subRegions) {
      getRegionsLabelFromTerritoryList(region.subRegions, activeRegions)
    }
  })

  return activeRegions
}
```

Comment: This no longer looks like it requires recursion. I see no recursive substructures anymore.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Hmm, it feel to me that it should be solved recursively as there can be an infinite level of depth in `subRegion` of  `regions`

Comment: Are you sure the input structure is the way you posted it? Right now, the top level `regions` array contains one object (Europe), *and one array* (an array which contains Africa), which seems quite unusual. Should the Africa object be on the top level of the outer array instead?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oops, it's late here... fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `Africa` object is supposed to be on the top level, `filter` the top-level objects by whether their `subRegions` satisfy the recursive test (a test that checks whether `selectedTerritories` includes the code of the object being iterated over, or whether any of the `subRegions` children pass the test):

```js
const regions = [{
  name: 'Europe',
  subRegions: [{
    name: 'BeNeLux',
    territories: [{
      code: 'NL',
      name: 'Netherlands'
    }, {
      code: 'DE',
      name: 'Germany'
    }, {
      code: 'LU',
      name: 'Luxembourg'
    }]
  }],
  territories: [{
    code: 'UK',
    name: 'United Kingdom'
  }, {
    code: 'AL',
    name: 'Albania'
  }, {
    code: 'ZW',
    name: 'Switzerland'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Africa',
  territories: [{
    code: 'GH',
    name: 'Ghana'
  }]
}];

const selectedTerritories = ['NL', 'UK', 'GH'];

const regionPasses = ({ subRegions, territories }) => (
  territories.some(({ code }) => selectedTerritories.includes(code))
  || (subRegions && subRegions.some(regionPasses))
);
    
const topSelected = regions
  .filter(regionPasses)
  .map(({ name }) => name);
console.log(topSelected);
```

To make things less computationally complex, you could turn `selectedTerritories` into a Set first (turning an `O(n)` operation into an `O(1)` operation):

```js
const regions = [{
  name: 'Europe',
  subRegions: [{
    name: 'BeNeLux',
    territories: [{
      code: 'NL',
      name: 'Netherlands'
    }, {
      code: 'DE',
      name: 'Germany'
    }, {
      code: 'LU',
      name: 'Luxembourg'
    }]
  }],
  territories: [{
    code: 'UK',
    name: 'United Kingdom'
  }, {
    code: 'AL',
    name: 'Albania'
  }, {
    code: 'ZW',
    name: 'Switzerland'
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Africa',
  territories: [{
    code: 'GH',
    name: 'Ghana'
  }]
}];

const selectedTerritories = new Set(['NL', 'UK', 'GH']);

const regionPasses = ({ subRegions, territories }) => (
  territories.some(({ code }) => selectedTerritories.has(code))
  || (subRegions && subRegions.some(regionPasses))
);
    
const topSelected = regions
  .filter(regionPasses)
  .map(({ name }) => name);
console.log(topSelected);
```

You could achieve the same result with a single outer loop rather than two (`.reduce` or something instead of `.filter` followed by `.map`), but I think this is clearer.

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me, check this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ymzGgZ?editors=1111 it should only output Europe instead

Comment: Oops, there need to be two `.some`s in the recursive `regionPasses`